# infiview like plugin for jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

is there any plugin available as infiview for jquery or any other open source similar ?
here is link to live example,
http://infiview.bindows.net/tomcat/InfiView/2.0/test/EdgesTester.html

Thank you for any input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using http://jsplumb.org/ i have achieved it.